# Pandas: How to append a row in multiindex dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have an empty data-frame (with NaN), there are two index levels (***‘Index’ and ‘Data_set’***) and three columns, as shown below.

```
 multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('ind1', 'set1'),
                                         ('ind1','set2'),
                                         ('ind1','set3'),
                                         ('ind2', 'set4'),
                                         ('ind2','set5'),
                                        ],
                                       names=['Indxe','Data_set'])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['data1','data2','condition'],index=multi_index)
```

[image]

Now I want to do two things,
First, I want to add a row with index in first index level. For example, I want to add ***set_NEW*** in ***ind1***.

[image]

And second, I want to add a row in the second index level. for example, adding the row in ***ind1,set1***

[image]

(Here, I have constructed separate data-frames to given the examples)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need recreate MultiIndex by new in [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('ind1', 'set1'),
                                 ('ind1','set2'),
                                 ('ind1','set3'),
                                 ('ind1','set_NEW'),
                                 ('ind2', 'set4'),
                                 ('ind2','set5')],names=['Indxe','Data_set'])
 
df = df.reindex(mux)
print (df)
               data1 data2 condition
Indxe Data_set                      
ind1  set1       NaN   NaN       NaN
      set2       NaN   NaN       NaN
      set3       NaN   NaN       NaN
      set_NEW    NaN   NaN       NaN
ind2  set4       NaN   NaN       NaN
      set5       NaN   NaN       NaN
```

---

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('ind1', 'set1'),
                                 ('ind1', 'set1'),
                                 ('ind1','set2'),
                                 ('ind1','set3'),
                                 ('ind1','set_NEW'),
                                 ('ind2', 'set4'),
                                 ('ind2','set5')],names=['Indxe','Data_set'])
 
df = df.reindex(mux)
print (df)
               data1 data2 condition
Indxe Data_set                      
ind1  set1       NaN   NaN       NaN
      set1       NaN   NaN       NaN
      set2       NaN   NaN       NaN
      set3       NaN   NaN       NaN
      set_NEW    NaN   NaN       NaN
ind2  set4       NaN   NaN       NaN
      set5       NaN   NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. actually I have done the same (the examples I have given). However, I have to append multiple rows and using MultiIndex all the time is not efficient.